# Is verifying receipts against the sandbox URL in a production app safe?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Apple's [Technical Note TN2259 "Adding In-App Purchase to your iOS and Mac Applications"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html) mentions the following:

> Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store.

But isn't this a security threat? I mean, can someone use a test account to create a sandbox receipt that will allow them to make a purchase without the actual payment?

Comment: Wouldn't someone have to have access to your iTunes connect to make a test account that could purchase your product?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Since receipt verification is done by sending the receipt to https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt without any authentication, it looks like a valid receipt from **any** test account, not necessarily mine, will be verified successfully.

Comment: Ah, I was confused about this and for some reason thought that verification involved verifying the receipt was for the correct product as well. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox receipts and test accounts are not valid for production apps so your concern is unfounded.

Comment: Receipt verification is done by our server, not by the app, so what if someone uses a hacked app or some other way to send a sandbox receipt to our server?

Comment: All of us do receipt verification at the server.  Again, the receipt would have been purchased with a "test account".  Nothing purchased from a test account is valid for downloading against production. If you don't believe me, try signing into your device with a test account.  Then try to make a purchase from the App Store.  It's not going to work.

Comment: But a malicious user can use some kind of their own test app to create a valid test receipt and then send it to our server to "purchase" a subscription completely bypassing our production app.

Comment: @SlimShaggy: Please forgive me but I don't believe this.  Is this a theory you are positing or do you have proof that this scam actually works?  If so, please post some evidence as I would like to see it.  We've tried negative testing using dev receipt against production and it simply does not work.

Comment: It's a theory, but I can see absolutely no reason for this not to work given that a valid sandbox receipt is somehow delivered to the server, and the server makes no distinction between sandbox and production receipts.

Comment: IMHO you are spinning your wheels.  I've told you multiple times that we have tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: I think what SlimShaggy is not seeing is that Apple knows whether your app is in production or sandbox (development) mode. The receipt includes info on the identity of your app. I'm assuming that Apple will thus not let a production app validate a sandbox receipt.